# Почему дата с datapicker angular показывает прошлый день?

Tags: javascript, angular4

Здравствуйте. Использую datapicker с angular material. Вот код:

```
<td [formGroup]="item">
 <div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date" formControlName="date">
 </div>
</td>
```

Datapicker находится в форме которая при отправке отправляет его значение на сервер. Но проблема в том что значения передается за прошлый день. К примеру, я выбрал **1/18/2018**, но отправило на сервер **2018-01-17T22:00:00.000Z**. Странно то, что angular pipe для date конвертит дату правильно, но перед тем как вывести, у меня на сервере есть запрос на группирование по месяцу и первый день нового месяца подпадает в последний день предыдущего. Может кто-то стыкался с такой проблемой. Спасибо.

Comment: Дайте `timezone` -> `getTimezoneOffset()`

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2628

Comment: const d = new Date(value.date); console.log(d.getTimezoneOffset()); >> -120

Comment: Вот линк на решение проблемы которую я сам решил
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224785/why-is-the-date-in-datepicker-angular-showing-the-last-day/50610224#50610224

Answer (score 0):

> К примеру, я выбрал 1/18/2018, но отправило на сервер 2018-01-17T22:00:00.000Z.

Дата и время передается в формате UTC. Это значит что сервер должен воспринимать ее именно так, в формате UTC (время по Лондону). Нельзя из строки вычленять только дату и не смотреть на время. Надо рассматривать строку целиком. Это стандартный способ серилизации даты и времени в js, который избавляет от многих проблем, связанных с часовыми поясами.

Comment: В консоли выполните

(new Date()).toJSON()

Мне показало такое:
"2018-01-13T12:53:16.036Z"

При серилизации мне показывает 12:53, вместо 15:53 т.е. смещение на 3 часа (UTC+3) относительно моего положения и Лондона.

Если сервер стоит где-то в Сан-Франциско, то там UTC-7 и в этот момент там будет 12-7 = 5:53